# Resolving a remote $HOME directory via FTP/SFTP

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ftp, sftp

In Objective-C, NSString has a method called

```
stringByExpandingTildeInPath
```

This method will take a string like "~/Documents" and resolve it to "/Users/Nick/Documents". The "~" tilde is resolved to the home directory of the current user of the machine the program is running on.

Now my question is this... I am writing a little FTP/SFTP utility using Cocoa and Objective-C. How could I resolve a tilde (~) path on remote machine via FTP/SFTP?

For example. A user wants to upload a file to

```
sftp://remote-host.com:~/
```

If remote-host.com is a Linux or OSX server, then this path is totally valid. However uploading a file only works when I specify the absolute path. I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the framework I'm using, [ConnectionKit](http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/), or if this is something that I need to manually implement. I'm ok with the latter but, any suggestions on how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try just removing the "~/" (and use the rest as a relative path) - generally the server should put you in the user's home directory by default when you connect.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of that... Definitely works. Thanks.